# mysqld clogging up memory: Ubuntu

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, mysql-python, pymysql

[image: Mysqld processes] 
We have some python programs scheduled and run by airflow that talks to mysql server in another node. We tunnel to the mysql server and connect to it with pymsql library(Python3.6).

Over a period of time I see so many mysqld processes running and are clogging up some memory in the node. If someone could see a potential problem here and help me solve it will be much appreciated

Comment: see mysql error logs and/or try to find errors with https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-errors.html

Comment: @Piyuesh sure will do that, but looking at the problem it doesn't look like error cases but more of connection leak or something

Comment: maybe `cursor.close()` and `db.close()` missing from your scripts